# Vectorized numpy functions to get elements of array between bounds defined by other array

Tags: python, numpy

If I have

```
data = np.array([97, 98, 99, 100])
offsets = np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4])
```

then I'd like to do

```py
result = []
for i in range(len(offsets)-1):
    result.append(data[offsets[i]: offsets[i+1]])
```

and get

```py
[array([97]),
 array([98]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([99]),
 array([], dtype=int64),
 array([100])]
```

This works, but is slow when `data` gets large-ish.

Is there any vectorized operation I could make use of here to speed it up?

Comment: There are some tricks that convert the slices into an `advanced indexing` array, allowing you to do a `data[idx]` operation.  But the result will be 1d, `[97,98,99,100]`.  You can't get a mix of (), (1,), (n,) shaped arrays with 'vectorization'.

Comment: In your use case, would it be ok to pad the output with NaNs or some other value so the output can be a non-ragged array, i.e. every row would have the same number of elements?

Comment: Not an answer but list comprehension could be used here and should be a bit faster. Probably hard to get around some kind of list comprehension when using numpy because of the mixed dimensions. Maybe when using ragged arrays its possible, e.g. [akward](https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Taking multiple slices can be converted to advanced indexing - with a possible, but not promised speedup.

A first stab at your example:

```
In [179]: idx=np.arange(len(data))[:,None]    
In [180]: idx2=(idx>=offsets[:-1])&(idx<offsets[1:])    
In [181]: idx2
Out[181]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False,  True]])
```

So in each column, we have `True` for the elements we want.

An iterative way of using that mask is:

```
In [182]: [data[i] for i in idx2.T]
Out[182]: 
[array([97]),
 array([98]),
 array([], dtype=int32),
 array([99]),
 array([], dtype=int32),
 array([100])]
```

The same as your slice result, but I expect it will be slower.

In other cases masks like this can be flattened, and used with just one `data[idx]` step.

The best I can do here is use `any`, but that looses most of that iterative structure

```
In [183]: idx2.any(axis=1)
Out[183]: array([ True,  True,  True,  True])
In [184]: data[idx2.any(axis=1)]
Out[184]: array([ 97,  98,  99, 100])
```

This `array_split` produces the same list, but internally it is also doing an iteration/append

```
In [221]: np.array_split(data,(1,2,2,3,3))
Out[221]: 
[array([97]),
 array([98]),
 array([], dtype=int32),
 array([99]),
 array([], dtype=int32),
 array([100])]
```